# remove numeric numbers between the text in cell

Tags: excel

Hi i have sheet with some of my photo names with numeric numbers. I want to remove this numbers. For ex

```
Cell A                    |    Cell B 
---------------------------------------------
My-photo-name-120X230.jpg |  my-photo-name.jpg
----------------------------------------------
photo-you-name-240x320.jpg| photo-you-name.jpg
```

Hope you understand my question. thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also "X" is not a number but also should be deleted? Is there a (mathematical) logical rule?

Comment: @DirkReichel   tried text to columns tool both way fixed width and enter special character. i also try  '=LEFT(A4,LEN(A4)-SEARCH("x",A4)-4)'   code but not got what i want . yes x is not number no problm in this this is in their because its show photo size like 120x230 if numbers will remove by anyway i can remove x via search and replace tool . thanks

Comment: The name will always be `"sometext"-***X***.jpg`? If yes, then `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-12)&".jpg"` should do...

Comment: @DirkReichel thanks dear its work . can you please post it in answer so i can mark this answer work and also vote for you .. thanks again dear ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the last pattern is always like `-###X###.jpg` then the formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-12)&".jpg"
```

will do. Or

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-12)&RIGHT(A1,4)
```

if not all pictures are `*.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Sub RemoveNumbersFromStrings()
        Set rNg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7")
        For Each rCell In rNg.Cells
            If rCell.Value <> "" Or rCell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                vAr = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").Value)
                vAr2 = Mid(vAr, InStr(vAr, ".") - 7, InStr(vAr, " -") + 7)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b1").Value = Replace(vAr, vAr2, "")
            End If
        Next rCell
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If vba is allowed then regex is a good tool for this.

```
  pattern  = "\d+x\d+"
  replacement = ""
  dim rgx as new regex(pattern)
  range("A1").value = rgx.replace(range("A1").value, replacement)
```

This should do it, have not tested it as I'm typing on my phone.
The code fixes A1, but can be looped to suit.